# Как сделать ожидание ввода фразы в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно, чтобы мой голосовой ассистент определённое время ждал ввода команды (фразы) в терминале. Я не знаю, как это сделать и не смог найти библиотеку под мой случай.

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-time.html   -  библиотека для работы со временем.
input () - стандартная функция ввода.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы input работал только 20 мин

Comment: @Spartak Я не смогу сделать Input c таймаутом, так как он выполняется до того момента, пока что-то не будет введено

Answer (score -1):

**main.py**

```
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        main
# Author:      ALEX
# Created:     19.07.2019
# Copyright:   (c) ALEX 2019
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QSystemTrayIcon
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from tray_menu import TrayMenu
from bot import Bot


class CoputerVoiceControl(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Desktop)

        self.tray_menu = TrayMenu(self)
        self.tray_menu.showMessage(
            "Голосовое управление компьютером",
            "Когда загорится зелёный скажите Анжела",
            QSystemTrayIcon.Information, 1000)

        self.bot = Bot()
        self.bot.status.connect(self.status_bot)
        self.bot.start()

    def status_bot(self, status):
        print(status)
        if status == "ready":
            self.tray_menu.setIcon(QIcon(self.resource_path("start.gif")))

    def resource_path(self, relative):
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative)
        else:
            return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    coputer_voice_control = CoputerVoiceControl()
    coputer_voice_control.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**tray_menu.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class TrayMenu(QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.menu()

    def menu(self):
        self.show_action = QAction("О программе", self)
        self.quit_action = QAction("Выход", self)

        # self.show_action.triggered.connect(self.info)
        self.quit_action.triggered.connect(self.exit)

        self.tray_menu = QMenu(self.parent)

        self.tray_menu.addAction(self.show_action)

        self.tray_menu.addAction(self.quit_action)

        self.setContextMenu(self.tray_menu)

        self.setIcon(QIcon(self.resource_path("stop.gif")))

        self.show()

    def exit(self):
        self.hide()
        QCoreApplication.quit()

    def resource_path(self, relative):
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative)
        else:
            return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative)
```

**bot.py**

```
import os
import glob
import speech_recognition
from speech_recognition import (Microphone, Recognizer, UnknownValueError,\
    RequestError)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class Bot(QThread):
    status = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.microphone = Microphone()
        self.recognizer = Recognizer()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        print("Минутку тишины, пожалуйста...")
        with self.microphone as microphone:
            self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(microphone)
        while True:
            self.status.emit("ready")
            try:
                with self.microphone as microphone:
                    audio = self.recognizer.listen(microphone)
                self.status.emit("processing")
                text_value = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru_RU")
                print("Вы сказали: " + text_value)
                if text_value.lower() == "анжела":
                    print("слушаю")
                    self.commandExecution()
            except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError as error:
                self.status.emit("value_error")
            except speech_recognition.RequestError as error:
                self.status.emit("request_error")

    def commandExecution(self):
        print("Минутку тишины, пожалуйста...")
        #with self.microphone as source:
        #    self.recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        while True:
            self.status.emit("ready")
            try:
                with self.microphone as source:
                    audio = self.recognizer.listen(source)
                self.status.emit("processing")

                text_value = self.recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru_RU")
                print("Вы сказали комманду: " + text_value.lower())

                if text_value.lower() == "открой блокнот":
                    os.popen("notepad")
                    return
                elif text_value.lower() == "запусти игровой центр" or "открой игровой центр":
                    if 
os.path.exists("C:\\Users\\ALEX\\AppData\Local\\GameCenter\\GameCenter.exe"):
                    
os.popen("C:\\Users\\ALEX\\AppData\Local\\GameCenter\\GameCenter.exe")
                    else:
                    
os.popen("D:\\Users\\ALEX\\AppData\Local\\GameCenter\\GameCenter.exe")
                    return
            except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError as error:
                self.status.emit("value_error")
                print("Command error: " + "UnknownValueError")
            except speech_recognition.RequestError as error:
                self.status.emit("request_error")
                print("Command error: " + "RequestError")
```